# undetectable virtualization apps to spoof web browsers

Tags: web-browser, virtualization, risk-analysis

monitoring web pages for malicious iframes (root kits) without VM is not safe. when its possible to detect virtualization just by [javascript](http://carnal0wnage.attackresearch.com/2009/04/detecting-vmware-with-javascript-or-how.html), which software provide undetectable VMs ? QEMU is safe?

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript runs within a tightly controlled browser.  There is no way of identifying detailed information about the environment that the browser is running on top of,  unless of course you exploit the browser and obtain remote code execution.   Even then it may be difficult to determine that you are running inside a virtual environment.

Comment: i just linked a working vm detector script in my question ...

Comment: @w00dy most browsers do not support activex,  and IE probably won't let this component run by default.  Also it is trivial to spoof your mac address.

Comment: there is too many ways to detect VM so maybe its better you suggest an undetectable virtual machine software instead of denying detection methods ...

Comment: @w00dy not from within a sandbox...  there is literally zero.